# How to create unique and composite index on django model using mongo db

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm using djangi and have created one model `Person` with few fields and want to implement indexing for efficient results.

I've done indexing on SQL but with mongoengine I'm doing for first time.
I'm stuck on how to implement unique index on the `name` column
and also how to implement a composite index on `phone_number and email` fields.

Thanks for the help

```
from mongoengine import Document, fields


class MongoDocument(object):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode_class(self)

    def to_dict(self):
        return convert_to_dict(self)

class Person(Document, MongoDocument):
    name = fields.StringField(max_length=250)
    phone_number = fields.StringField(max_length=10)
    email = fields.StringField(max_length=250)
    active = fields.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: As per the mongoengine Documentation, you just need to add `unique=True` to a field. i. e. `name = fields.StringField(max_length=250, unique=True)`

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is uniqueness, you can use `index=True` in the field definition (e.g `name = fields.StringField(max_length=250, unique=True)`). If you want composite index or more fancy index definition, you can pass the index definition to the `meta` attribute, as described in the corresponding [MongoEngine doc](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#indexes).
Below is the example from the official doc

```
class Page(Document):
    category = IntField()
    title = StringField()
    rating = StringField()
    created = DateTimeField()
    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            'title',
            '$title',  # text index
            '#title',  # hashed index
            ('title', '-rating'),
            ('category', '_cls'),
            {
                'fields': ['created'],
                'expireAfterSeconds': 3600
            }
        ]
    }
```